# When are my Azure application registration/service principal credentials going to expire?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

So that our Azure Web Apps can access Azure Key Vault, we use certificates and application registrations with service principals.

After generating a certificate, we use the following Azure PowerShell to create an application registration and service principal and then give the service principal access to the Azure Key Vault. The Web App then loads this certificate and uses it to authenticate with Azure Key Vault. It all works fine.

```bsh
$subscriptionId = Read-Host -Prompt 'SubscriptionId'
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$resourceGroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Resource group name'
$vaultName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Vault name'
$certificateName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Certificate name'
$applicationName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Application name'

$certificatePath = Join-Path (Get-Location) "$certificateName.cer"
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificate.Import($certificatePath)

$rawCertData = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificate.GetRawCertData())
$now = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow

$application = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -HomePage "https://$applicationName" -IdentifierUris "https://$applicationName" -CertValue $rawCertData -StartDate $now -EndDate $now.AddYears(1)

$servicePrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $application.ApplicationId

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VaultName $vaultName -ServicePrincipalName "https://$applicationName" -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

The problem is this line:

```bsh
$application = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -HomePage "https://$applicationName" -IdentifierUris "https://$applicationName" -CertValue $rawCertData -StartDate $now -EndDate $now.AddYears(1)
```

It sets the `StartDate` and `EndDate` to the current date and the current date plus 1 year. In hindsight I think it should have been the certificate start and end date:

```bsh
$application = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -HomePage "https://$applicationName" -IdentifierUris "https://$applicationName" -CertValue $rawCertData -StartDate` $certificate.NotBefore -EndDate $certificate.NotAfter
```

**My question is - what will happen after `$now.AddYears(1)`?** The certificate was created with a 3 year expiry but the application registration/service principal was created with an earlier `EndDate` - but what does that mean?

Comment: I have not tested this scenario, but I would *guess* it will not accept requests signed with that certificate anymore after 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it's the effective end date for the credential so I would assume the credential would stop working at that time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-5.1.1

You can use New-AzureRmADAppCredential to roll the secret before that time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-5.1.1

Comment: You were right, the error you get is `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key used is expired., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'XXXXXXXCERTIFICATETHUMBPRINTXXXXX', Found key 'Start=02/10/2017, End=02/10/2018, Thumbprint=XXXXXXXXX', Configured keys: [Key0:Start=02/10/2017, End=02/10/2018, Thumbprint=XXXXXXXXXX;]]`. Using `New-AzureRmADAppCredential` with a longer expiry (same certificate) did the job.